# Issue with creating a transitioning sidebar with containers

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sidebar which can extend using the hover function. I've made the sidebar using a jumbotron, combined with a container. Currently it does not extend at all.

```css
.jumbotron {
  padding: 55px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1400px;
  transition: width 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.jumbotron:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.parallax1 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/flowers-276014_640.jpg");

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 jumbotron jumbotron-fluid parallax1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">

        <h1><b></b>The Magical Codex</h1>
        <h2><em>of the Mega Gay Zone</em></h2>
        <h4>By Josh Azoneb</h4>

        <p>blah blah blah</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `jumbotron jumbotron-fluid parallax1` ?  --> [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is i'm thinking that will work

```
 .jumbotron {
      padding: 55px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 30px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin-left: -20px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 1400px;
      transition: width 1s;
      transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .jumbotron:hover {
      width: 300px;
    }

    .parallax1 {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/flowers-276014_640.jpg");
    
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      border-radius: 30px;
      width: 400px;
    }

    .content {
      padding-left: 20px; /* Adjust based on your preference */
    }
```

this is the html code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid parallax1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 content">
      <h1><b>The Magical Codex</b></h1>
      <h2><em>of the Mega Gay Zone</em></h2>
      <h4>By Josh Azoneb</h4>

      <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```